# Reducing Matrix For General Solution

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

[image]

for a general solution:
$$ \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2s - 3t\\s\\t \end{bmatrix} $$, where s, t are arbitrary parameters.

Why is the general solution as stated above with two arbitrary parameters? I assume that it is because having three arbitrary parameters does not tell us anything interesting or further than what we already know going into the problem. Whereas with two arbitrary parameters we can now understand some additional relationship across the solution? Is there another general solution that can be found?

Comment: Is your first matrix equation really what you wanted to say?

Comment: Yeah I have written it correctly...perhaps I have done something incorrect in the reduction? Or should I not reduce the first matrix any further? technically it is a system of equations...I was just lazy and wrote it as a matrix and vector

Comment: So a non-zero three-by-three matrix really does equal a zero column vector?

Comment: yes that is as per the book that i am reading ( Linear Algebra 1 pg 83) Ma Siu Lun, Victor Tan and Ng Kah Loon

Comment: I believe you mean $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&3\\2&-4&6\\3&-6&9\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I have added an image of the example...perhaps i have translated it incorrectly...apologies...I am struggling to make sense of it all still

Comment: No problem. The system in your picture would actually have a corresponding matrix equation as I have written it in my previous comment, rather than what you have in the body of your question. The addition of the vector $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$ is actually quite important.

Comment: ahh okay...sorry and thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&3\\2&-4&6\\3&-6&9\end{bmatrix}$$ is not invertible. This is because the second and third rows are multiples of the first, so by adding $-2$ times the first row to the second row, and by adding $-3$ times the first row to the third row we have the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}1&-2&3\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$which has determinant $0$ obviously. Hence, $A$ has determinant $0$ and is therefore not invertible. Therefore, we cannot row reduce $A$ to the identity matrix. That is, we cannot reduce the matrix in question to $$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$
From the above argument we see that $A$ has rank $1$ and nullity $2$. This is why there are two "arbitrary parameters", or free variables, in the solution system (because the nullity, the dimension of the kernel, is $2$).

Comment: Wonderful...this makes sense finally :)

Comment: so is the # of free variables always equal to the nullity?

Comment: Yes. This is because the nullity is the dimension of the kernel, i.e. the dimension of the solution space to $A\vec x=\vec 0$. So the dimension corresponds to how many free variables we have.

Comment: Thanks a million this was super helpful!

Comment: Excellent! Happy to help. Any further questions just let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You have a two-parametric solution because your linear system is in fact, *one* simultaneous equations with three unknowns.   The other two are just scalar multiples of the first and don't impart any new constraints on the variables' freedom.

$$\begin{array}{l:l}{x-2y+3z = 0 \\ 2x-4y+6z=0 \\ 3x-6y+9z=0}&{x-2y+3z = 0 \\ 2(x-2y+3z)=0 \\ 3(x-2y+3z)=0}\end{array}$$

So all you can say is $x=2y-3z$

... or, if you will, that $x=2s-3t$ when $y\gets s, z\gets t$
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=s\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-3\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thanks Graham....this is very clear...appreciate the answer !!